# how does the code work "x=np.vstack([range(7)[i:i+3] for i in range(5)])"

Tags: python, numpy

i'm on studying numpy and middle of studying "scalar and vector, matrix multiplication" , i'm on trouble.

i'd like to know how the code below works

```
x=np.vstack([range(7)[i:i+3] for i in range(5)])
```

and its out come is

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4],
   [3, 4, 5],
   [4, 5, 6]])
```

i want to kow why i need first range(range(7)) and why first range should be 7 or higher?

when i did

```
x=np.vstack([range(3)[1:4])
```

its outcome is

```
array([[0,1])
```

so i assumed range(n) must be the showing number count

so i thought when i write code like this

```
x=np.vstack([range(4)[i:i+3] for i in range(5)])
```

, the output would be same with when range(7)

but the output is *ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 2 has size 2*

why?

Comment: Try this:-
print([range(7)[i:i + 3] for i in range(5)])
I think that will clarify things for you

Comment: Try playing with it without the `np.vstack`, just as `[range(4)[i:i+3] for i in range(5)]`

Answer (score 0):

Let's go inside out

```
In [171]: [range(7)[i:i+3] for i in range(5)]
Out[171]: [range(0, 3), range(1, 4), range(2, 5), range(3, 6), range(4, 7)]
```

as you can see, you have a list of ranges, all of length 3, the last one has as second limit the limit of the original range.  What happens if we reduce the range of the original?

```
In [172]: [range(6)[i:i+3] for i in range(5)]
Out[172]: [range(0, 3), range(1, 4), range(2, 5), range(3, 6), range(4, 6)]
```

the last range has a length that is different from the previous others, and so the whole list of ranges is non-homogeneous and unfit to be used in `vstack`.

In your example, 3 is the number of columns, `ncols` and 5 the number of rows, `nrows`, of the resulting matrix, and the last row starts at `nrows-1` and the last element of the matrix is `nrows-1+ncols-1`, finally this number, as we have seen previously, must be STRICTLY smaller than the width of the original range, hence the original range must be STRICTLY larger than 6, i.e., 7 or a larger number.

As a final remark, using `np.vstack` is unnecessary, we have the same result using `np.array`